# How to limit code execution to a few pre-defined users without getUserLoginId (google apps script)

Tags: google-apps-script

i have a google script that runs on my google sheet that sends emails based off of a column.

I want that script to only be able to be run by a few pre-defined users. i.e., i think i need a way to have the code check who the current user is and compare that to a list of authorized code executors.

However, getUserLoginId and getUserEmail aren't working because the users and I are in different domains, so that just returns null.

Is there any other way to limit which users can/can't execute a function in the code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Session.getActiveUser.getEmail()` to get the email of active user. Then you may compare this email Id with an array of allowed emailIds.

Here is a sample code snippet.

```
function myFunction(){
  if (isAllowed()){
    //Send email etc
  }
}


function isAllowed(){
  var allowed = false;
  var currentUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var allowedUsers = ['email1@gmail.com', 'email2@gmail.com', 'email3@gmail.com'];
  if(allowedUsers.indexOf(currentUser) != -1){
    allowed = true;
  }
  return allowed;
}
```